# How to i save my game currency in unity 3d using playerprefs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I want to create an in-game store for my game and I want to save the money with player prefs but the code isn't working

```
public float AmountNumber;
public Text AmountText;

void Start() {
    AmountText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Amount").ToString();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    AmountText.text = AmountNumber.ToString();

    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Amount", AmountNumber);
}
```

Comment: it has not any error and it run on my side,is it the final script? i assume that the code is not whole of code, for example the class definition and inheritance from Monobehaviour, .... and does it assign correctly to a **gameobject** in your scene?

Comment: `but the code isn't working` is no valid problem description .. what exactly is your issue?

Comment: Also please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 1):

In the `Start` you only update your display with the stored value so `AmountNumber` will stay `0` and then in `Update` overwrite the value in the `PlayerPrefs` with `0`

... rather do

```
void Start() 
{
    AmountNumber = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Amount");
    AmountText.text = AmountNumber.ToString();
}
```

---

Then in general you should not do the rest in `Update` **every frame** but rather make your code more event driven.

I would e.g. rather make the actual value `private` and rather have a property like e.g.

```
private int _amountNumber;

public int AmountNumber
{
    get => _amountNumber;
    set
    {
        _amountNumber = value;
        AmountText.text = value.ToString();
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Amount", value);
    }
}

private void Start ()
{
    AmountNumber = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Amount");
}
```

This way whenever something assigns a value to the `AmountNumber` property it automatically also

- updates the display
- stores the value in the player prefs

without having to do it each and every frame.

Comment: Is there any other way

Comment: @MobileGamer What do you not like about this approach?